# I want to continue my rownumber of data set in two tables in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I want to continue my rownumber of data set in two tables in ssrs.i.e
i have two tables,i want to start rownumber at end of another table

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter on your 2nd tablix/matrix to control row number